# How to set column width when Export HTML table to .CSV as excel file (JS only)

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table, export-to-csv

I am using this fantastic peace of code by *Konstantinos Krevatas* to export HTML table to .CSV in JavaScript.

```
var xport = {
  _fallbacktoCSV: true,  
  toXLS: function(tableId, filename) {   
    this._filename = (typeof filename == 'undefined') ? tableId : filename;

    //var ieVersion = this._getMsieVersion();
    //Fallback to CSV for IE & Edge
    if ((this._getMsieVersion() || this._isFirefox()) && this._fallbacktoCSV) {
      return this.toCSV(tableId);
    } else if (this._getMsieVersion() || this._isFirefox()) {
      alert("Not supported browser");
    }

    //Other Browser can download xls
    var htmltable = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var html = htmltable.outerHTML;

    this._downloadAnchor("data:application/vnd.ms-excel" + encodeURIComponent(html), 'xls'); 
  },
  toCSV: function(tableId, filename) {
    this._filename = (typeof filename === 'undefined') ? tableId : filename;
    // Generate our CSV string from out HTML Table
    var csv = this._tableToCSV(document.getElementById(tableId));
    // Create a CSV Blob
    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv" });
```

Is it possible to set the column width of the exported CSV file?

You can find all the code [here](https://codepen.io/kostas-krevatas/pen/mJyBwp)

Comment: CSV does not have column widths.

Comment: For excel take a look at sheet.js library and search for other potential libraries